# Ansible: how to deal with files that the current user does not have read permission (mode `0o600`)?

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-18.04, permission-denied

#### Environment

- Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop
- Ansible 2.10.0
- Python 3.6.9

#### Brief Description

I have a file `/tmp/hello.txz` that is owned by root and does not allow others to read/write:

```
-rw------- 1 root root 176 Mar 11 20:32 hello.txz
```

When I try to copy it to another location:

```
ansible -m copy -K --become -vvv -a "src='/tmp/hello.txz' dest='/tmp/new_location'" localhost
```

I get the following error:

```
localhost | FAILED! => {
    "msg": "an error occurred while trying to read the file '/tmp/hello.txz': [Errno 13] Permission denied: b'/tmp/hello.txz'"
}
```

When I try to unarchive it:

```
ansible -m unarchive -K --become -vvv -a "src='/tmp/hello.txz' dest='/tmp'" localhost
```

I get the same "Permission denied" error.

#### My Debugging Effort

After debugging into the source code, **I think the reasons are as follows**:

1. The modules `copy` and `unarchive` happen to have their corresponding action plugins: [copy](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.0/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py) and [unarchive](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.0/lib/ansible/plugins/action/unarchive.py).
2. The action plugins seem to be executed in the current, unprivileged user mode (i.e., prior to `become`) so it only has whatever permissions the current unprivileged user has.
3. But because the file is owned by `root` and doesn't allow others to read/write, the current, unprivileged user can't deal with the file.
4. `--become` seems to work for Ansible modules but not the corresponding action plugins.

One evidence is that the `EXEC` commands are not wrapped by `sudo` (:

```
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: ywen
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~ywen && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /home/ywen/.ansible/tmp `"&& mkdir "` echo /home/ywen/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615567945.1988397-2230-210988164993075 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1615567945.1988397-2230-210988164993075="` echo /home/ywen/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615567945.1988397-2230-210988164993075 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /home/ywen/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1615567945.1988397-2230-210988164993075/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
```

The "Permission denied" error that `copy` and `unarchive` report is caused by the [following `with` line](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.0/lib/ansible/parsing/dataloader.py#L362-L363):

```py
            if decrypt:
                with open(to_bytes(real_path), 'rb') as f:
```

#### An Unacceptable Workaround

To "fix" this issue for me, simply change the file mode from `0o600` to `0o644` to give the other users read/write permissions.

However, this wouldn't work for me. The file I want to deal with contains secrets that only `root` should be able to see. That's why the file was owned by `root` and doesn't allow others to read/write.

#### My Questions

1. I believe I should be able to develop a more complex playbook to deal with this kind of file. For example, I may run shell commands or even a small script. **But I'm also wondering if there is an easier and more concise way to deal with this kind of file.**
2. I guess I'm not the first one that encounters this issue, but I don't seem to find any other posts that talk about this. **Could you post the links if you know any of such discussion?**

Comment: Yes, the issue is that `become` is to have privilege escalation on remote hosts, if you want to access local file, the user running Ansible need permission to access those files. So change permissions of the file or run Ansible as root.

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question on the #ansible IRC channel, I got the confirmation from the Ansible developers that `become` is for remote hosts only. The action plugins are running in the context of the current user who launches the playbook and can do whatever the current user is limited to.

[image]

Therefore:

1. No. There isn't an easier and more concise way to deal with this kind of file. The current user must be able to read the file in order for further processing.
2. Fine. Maybe I'm truly the first one that deals with this weird situation...